# How to create a model instance that has a belongsTo property?

Tags: ember-data

```
var attr = DS.attr,
hasMany = DS.hasMany,
belongsTo = DS.belongsTo;

Admin.Category = DS.Model.extend({
    name: attr(),
    mstore: belongsTo('mstore')
});

console.log(mstore); // this is a PromiseObject object passed from "{{action createCategory mstore}}" tag
var newCategory = this.store.createRecord('category', {
    name: 'nn',
    mstore: mstore
});
```

I get an error like: 
   Assertion failed: You can only add a 'mstore' record to this relationship.

How can I set a belongsTo property using a PromiseObject object? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your {{action...}} you should pass a real model, not a promise. To get a model from a promise you need to do something like this:

```
var myMstore;

that.store.find('mstore', mstoreId).then(function(mstore) {
  myMstore = mstore;
});
```